# SP2013 mulit value dropdown to indidual row

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SP2013 list with a multi value Person dropdown. Upon submit instead of a single row with all users listed out, I'd like each person to have their own row.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, unfortunately, that's not possible, in SharePoint every row is an item, if you want to achieve that, you need to create a single item per user.

If you need this for reporting, you can export the list to Excel (Ribbon -> Library tab -> Export to Excel) and in there customize your report per every user.